# c# linq join with projection

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So in my shop app i'm allowing users to favorite items.
what i wish to do is to show the list of favorite items in the user profile page where the list is sorted on the like date in a descending order.

We have 2 tables that we need to join, one is items and the other one is favorites.

how would one join this two tables, so the result will answer this criteria:

1. The result will be a list of items that was favorite by this particular user.
2. The results will come with the list of comments for each item (each item have a list of comments).
3. The results will be sorted correctly.

So far i came up with this:

```
Items =
             await _context.Favorites
             .Join(
                 _context.Items,
                 f => f.ItemId,
                 i => i.Id,
                 (f, i) => new { f, i }) 
                 .Distinct()
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.f.FavDate)
                 .Select(x => x.i)
                 .Skip(skip).Take(take)
                 .Include(c => c.ListOfComments)
                 .ToListAsync();
```

This works but does not answer the first criteria, which is that only items favorite by particular user will be returned, this returns list of items favorite by the users and not by a particular user.

I tried to add a where clause before the join (_context.Favorites.Where(f.UserVoterId.equals(profileId)) but it throws an exception.

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: Hi, the exception i receive is :  Message "The expression '[x].i.ListOfComments' passed to the Include operator could not be bound."

Comment: shouldn't that be `_context.Favorites.Where(f => f.UserVoterId.Equals(profileId)).Join....`

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.Include` line and change `_context.Items` to read `_context.Items.Include(c => c.ListOfComments)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to:

- include the user id as the join key and
- load the data in separate steps

To select the favorite items of a specific user (`profileId`) you need this query:

```
var favorites = _context.Favorites.OrderByDescending(f => f.FavDate)
    .Join(_context.Items,
        fav => new { fav.ItemId, UserId = fav.UserVoterId },
        item => new { ItemId = item.Id, UserId = profileId },
        (fav, item) => item)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

And to load the comments just try one of the following (whichever works):

```
var itemIds = favorites.Select(f => f.Id);
var comments = _context.Comments.Where(c => itemIds.Contains(c.ItemId))
    .GroupBy(c => c.ItemId)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());
```

Or

```
var items = _context.Comments
    .GroupJoin(favorites,
        comment => comment.ItemId,
        favorite => favorite.Id,
        (fav, comments) => new
        {
            Item = fav,
            Comments = comment.ToArray()
        });
```

In the first case, the comments are added to a `Dictionary<TItemId, Comment>` where `TItemId` is the type of `item.Id` and to get the comments for an item you'd use

```
var itemComments = comments[item.Id];
```

which is a `O(1)` operation.

In the second case the `items` collection will have all the data you need so you'll have to project it into the structure that suits your needs.

**NB** I mentioned earlier *whichever works* because I'm not entirely sure that `GroupJoin` is properly translated to SQL and I'm not sure if I missed some requirements for the `GroupJoin` method.